# SAS dsnless connection to SQL server by passing in credentials

Tags: sas

I am trying to connect to a SQL server using dsnless connection in SAS. When I set the Trusted_Connection=Yes, it works. But when I try to pass in my windows credentials, it says Connection denined. I believe it is because the password has a special character.

```
%let PWD=Aug#2020;
libname test ODBC noprompt = "server=TOC11\DMS1;DRIVER=SQL Server;UID=s111;PWD=&PWD.;"  schema=dbo;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You might need to `%NRSTR` and `%` escape the special char. What is the special character ? What does the SAS log show ?  What happens if you change your password to just numbers and letters ?

Comment: Thanks. Error just shows 'Login failed for user s111'. Need to lookup nrstr.

Comment: Is that special character an asterisk? Cause yes, that will cause issues. It used to cause issues if we used that in the password in SAS EG as well.